# Mutable borrows in loops [Design help]

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping

I am new to Rust having gone through only the Rust book, working on a project which requires capturing a screenshot of the primary display. I am using the [scrap](https://github.com/quadrupleslap/scrap) crate for this.

```
 fn screen_shot_and_save_image(iter:i32) {
        let one_second = Duration::new(1, 0);
        let one_frame = one_second / 60;
        let mut buffer = None;
        let display = Display::primary().expect("Couldn't find primary display.");
        let mut capturer = Capturer::new(display).expect("Couldn't begin capture.");
        let (mut w, mut h) =  (capturer.width(), capturer.height());;
        
        while buffer.is_none() {
           // Wait until there's a frame.
            match capturer.frame() {
                Ok(buf) => {
                    buffer = Some(buf);
                }
                Err(error) => {
                    if error.kind() == WouldBlock {
                        // Keep spinning.
                        thread::sleep(one_frame);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        panic!("Error: {}", error);
                    }
                }
            };
        }   
        //work with buffer
    }
```

the capturer.frame() has a signature of

```
scrap::common::dxgi::Capturer

pub fn frame<'a>(&'a mut self) -> io::Result<Frame<'a>>
```

Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `capturer` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src\main.rs:103:15
    |
103 |         match capturer.frame() {
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `capturer` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

Based on similar questions, I understand that Rust does not allow mutable borrows in a loop. However I need to use this function in a while loop, incase I get the WouldBlock error, which returns a blank image intermittently. I cannot make good sense of the compiler error or suggestion so any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: `pub fn frame<'a>(&'a mut self) -> io::Result<Frame<'a>>` is identical to `pub fn frame(&mut self) -> io::Result<Frame<'_>>`, just fyi. I'll use that one in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume this is your minimal example, because I couldn't get your example running:

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

struct Capturer {
    data: String,
    iteration: u32,
}

impl Capturer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: "Captured data!".to_string(),
            iteration: 0,
        }
    }
    fn frame(&mut self) -> Result<&str, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        self.iteration += 1;
        if self.iteration == 3 {
            Ok(&self.data)
        } else {
            Err(format!("Incorrect iteration: {}", self.iteration).into())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = None;
    let mut capturer = Capturer::new();

    while buffer.is_none() {
        // Wait until there's a frame.
        match capturer.frame() {
            Ok(buf) => {
                buffer = Some(buf);
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("No result yet: {}", error);
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
            }
        };
    }

    //work with buffer
    println!("Received: '{}'", buffer.unwrap());
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `capturer` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |         match capturer.frame() {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `capturer` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

### Problem

The return value of `capturer.frame()` contains a *lifetime*. That means that some part of the return value is referencing `capturer`. And because `.frame()` uses `self` as `&mut self`, it is assumed that this is a mutable borrow, and there can only ever be one mutable borrow at a time.

Because you store the result outside of the loop, Rust does not allow you to loop any more, because the next iteration of the loop might call `.frame()` again although you still have a mutable reference.

### Solution

I think the real solution here is to avoid all of that and use the fact that Rust loops themselves can have a value:

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

struct Capturer {
    data: String,
    iteration: u32,
}

impl Capturer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: "Captured data!".to_string(),
            iteration: 0,
        }
    }
    fn frame(&mut self) -> Result<&str, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        self.iteration += 1;
        if self.iteration == 3 {
            Ok(&self.data)
        } else {
            Err(format!("Incorrect iteration: {}", self.iteration).into())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut capturer = Capturer::new();

    let buffer = loop {
        // Wait until there's a frame.
        match capturer.frame() {
            Ok(buf) => {
                break buf;
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("No result yet: {}", error);
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
            }
        };
    };

    //work with buffer
    println!("Received: '{}'", buffer);
}
```

```
No result yet: Incorrect iteration: 1
No result yet: Incorrect iteration: 2
Received: 'Captured data!'
```

Comment: Thank you for framing the problem so neatly and providing a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the borrow checker to stop complaining if you're a bit more explicit about exactly when your loop will end:

```rust
let buffer = loop {
    // Wait until there's a frame.
    match capturer.frame() {
        Ok(buf) => {
            break buf;
        }
        Err(error) => { ... }
    };
}
```

If this works (I haven't tested it), it's because it proves to the borrow checker that the result of `capturer.frame()`, which is stored in `buffer`, won't exist concurrently with another call to `capturer.frame()`. The compiler is not very smart, and can't see that `buffer.is_none()` implies `buffer` isn't storing `capturer.frame()`.